# What pointer-related things don't work in Delphi XE8's mobile compilers?

Tags: delphi, pointers, llvm, delphi-xe8

Embarcadero's docwiki page [LLVM-based Delphi Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/LLVM-based_Delphi_Compilers) lists several language changes in Delphi XE8. One of the bullets says:

> Use of pointers is not supported by LLVM-based Delphi compilers.

What exactly does this mean in practice? Which pointer-related things that used to work in Delphi XE7, no longer work in Delphi XE8? I can't seem to find in-depth explanation on this on Embarcadero's web site. The page [Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop) that's said to contain more information, does not mention the word "Pointer", for example.

Comment: I've come to learn you can't store pointers in the `Tag` property, or in general in an `NativeInt`. At least not on iOS and probably Android too. I'm in the middle of a completely re-design thanks to this, and the fact that everything *was* working just fine under Windows. Silly how something as simple as storing references on list items requires me to write an entirely separate list manager (for a `TListView` / `TListViewItem`).

Comment: @Jerry You certainly can store pointers in `Tag`. And in a `NativeInt`. What you can't do is hold managed types in unmanaged `Pointer` or `NativeInt` variables. Because managed types are, well, managed. It is no different on Windows when you would try to stuff strings, interfaces, dynamic arrays etc. in a non-managed pointer variable. You should ask yourself why you are using untyped pointers anyway? What's wrong with a good generic container?

Comment: @David That's my point, the `TListViewItem.Tag` property is not letting me use it to keep pointers to objects, as was possible in VCL. Well at least I can store one in it, but won't let me cast it back out. I've seen numerous other people face the precise issue. See for example: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/attaching-user-data-to-tlistvie/1988307

Comment: @Jerry It's just the same on Windows in essence. The change is nothing to do with pointers, or Tag, or NativeInt. The difference is that objects are managed for mobile targets, and unmanaged for desktop targets. So you run into trouble when you cast a managed type to a raw pointer irrespective of the target.

Comment: @David I should have said "Objects" not "Pointers" - I still have a lot to learn considering I'm still fresh to cross-platforms.

Comment: @JerryDodge It doesn't change anything. I knew perfectly well what you meant. All my comments are written on that basis. Your mental model of what has changed isn't quite right. The key is that objects are unmanaged on desktop targets, and managed on next gen targets.

Comment: @JerryDodge, there was a blog recently, https://delphiaball.co.uk/2015/06/18/linking-objecttvalue-to-a-control-vcl-to-firemonkey/, where there are some alternatives to use instead. But my experience is that the less your business logic depends on the GUI, the better.

Comment: @LURD Thanks for that link, and actually I have multiple layers, including an in-between "adapter" layer between the UI and business logic, which basically links the two together.

Comment: @LURD Ha! You can just use TagObject and it's all good! Seriously, typeless properties like this aren't healthy.

Comment: @David Actually `TagObject` doesn't exist in a `TListViewItem`. Only `Tag`. I saw many people say that actually, who didn't realize a `TListViewItem` is actually a light-weight object instead of a control (contributing to the better performance of a `TListView` as opposed to a `TListBox`).

Comment: On the other hand, this article talks about using the `Data` property, where I saw in two places people saying not to use it because it's internally managed by FMX. Turns out those two remarks were incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Use of pointers is not supported by LLVM-based Delphi compilers.

That has to be an error in the documentation. Just take a look at the RTL. It is thick with the use of pointers.

For instance, how about `CompareMem`. It is defined like this:

```
function CompareMem(P1, P2: Pointer; Length: Integer): Boolean;
```

And the implementation runs like this:

```
function CompareMem(P1, P2: Pointer; Length: Integer): Boolean;
{$IF defined(POSIX)}
begin
  if Length <= 0 then
    Result := True
  else
    Result := memcmp(P1^, P2^, Length) = 0;
end;
{$ELSEIF defined(PUREPASCAL)}
....
{$ENDIF !PUREPASCAL}
```

The `POSIX` code is used by the mobile targets.

Or how about `TObject` which looks like this:

```
type
  TObject = class
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Free;
    procedure DisposeOf; {$IFNDEF AUTOREFCOUNT} inline; {$ENDIF}
    class function InitInstance(Instance: Pointer): TObject {$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT} unsafe {$ENDIF};
    procedure CleanupInstance;
    function ClassType: TClass; inline;
    class function ClassName: string;
    class function ClassNameIs(const Name: string): Boolean;
    class function ClassParent: TClass;
    class function ClassInfo: Pointer; inline;
    class function InstanceSize: Integer; inline;
    class function InheritsFrom(AClass: TClass): Boolean;
    class function MethodAddress(const Name: _ShortStr): Pointer; overload;
    class function MethodAddress(const Name: string): Pointer; overload;
    class function MethodName(Address: Pointer): string;
    class function QualifiedClassName: string;
    function FieldAddress(const Name: _ShortStr): Pointer; overload;
    function FieldAddress(const Name: string): Pointer; overload;
    function GetInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): Boolean;
    class function GetInterfaceEntry(const IID: TGUID): PInterfaceEntry;
    class function GetInterfaceTable: PInterfaceTable;
    class function UnitName: string;
    class function UnitScope: string;
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
    function __ObjAddRef: Integer; virtual;
    function __ObjRelease: Integer; virtual;
{$ENDIF}
    function Equals(Obj: TObject): Boolean; virtual;
    function GetHashCode: Integer; virtual;
    function ToString: string; virtual;
    function SafeCallException(ExceptObject: TObject;
      ExceptAddr: Pointer): HResult; virtual;
    procedure AfterConstruction; virtual;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; virtual;
    procedure Dispatch(var Message); virtual;
    procedure DefaultHandler(var Message); virtual;
    class function NewInstance: TObject {$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT} unsafe {$ENDIF}; virtual;
    procedure FreeInstance; virtual;
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  protected
{$ENDIF}
    destructor Destroy; virtual;

{$IFDEF CPP_ABI_SUPPORT}
    procedure CPP_ABI_1; virtual;
    procedure CPP_ABI_2; virtual;
    procedure CPP_ABI_3; virtual;
{$ENDIF !CPP_ABI_SUPPORT}

  protected
    function GetDisposed: Boolean; inline;
    procedure CheckDisposed; {$IFNDEF AUTOREFCOUNT} inline; {$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  private const
    objDestroyingFlag = Integer($80000000);
    objDisposedFlag = Integer($40000000);
  protected
    [Volatile] FRefCount: Integer;
    class procedure __MarkDestroying(const Obj); static; inline;
    class function __SetDisposed(const Obj): Boolean; static; inline;
  public
    property RefCount: Integer read FRefCount;
{$ENDIF}
    property Disposed: Boolean read GetDisposed;
  end;
```

It's pretty clear that pointers are used here on mobile platforms.

Have a read of the Embarcadero whitepaper on the subject: [The Delphi Language for Mobile Development](http://www.embarcadero.com/resources/white-papers?download=102). Again it covers the use of pointers on multiple occasions and it is clear that they are supported. Now, it's also true that the use of pointers is discouraged and if pointers can readily be avoided then your are encouraged to do so. But that's quite different from stating that pointers are not supported by the compilers.

It seems at the very least to be mildly ironic that Embarcadero are spreading FUD of their own products.

Comment: From the pdf: `Reduce or remove pointer usage, given direct usage of pointer is being discouraged as we
move towards some automatic memory management. Using generic container classes,
instead of TList (internally based on pointers) is a good example of the migration that the
Delphi RTL library is undergoing, and we suggest that Delphi developers perform similar
conversions in their code as well.`

Comment: And: `Use the generic container classes defined in the unit Generics.Collections. The old-style
Contnrs unit is not available on the mobile platform, because it is based on a pointer list
(the non-generic TList class) and won’t work properly with the ARC memory management
model.
`. and `Avoid any pointer-based structure and method, unless you are calling native APIs
requiring it.
`.

Comment: TList stuff has always been very type-unsafe, assigning raw untyped "void pointers" to any pointer-like variable, so to me the announcement about pointers not being supported looked like they had finally taken the next logical step and disabled raw pointer usage from user code altogether. The RTL feels like a special case to me anyway. I'll wait some time before accepting an answer.

Comment: The mobile compilers support pointers fine. `TList` is indeed to be avoided. If only the RTL/VCL would do so!! But pointers are still useful sometimes. Of course casting a managed object to a pointer is not good. But there are many other sane uses for pointers. It would be ironic if Emba made a big play on their "native" tools and then stopped anyone using pointers!

Comment: I can't say that the introduction of ARC has brought much good into the language. Mostly agony and perhaps even contraproductive amongst their (EMB) own development and developers. The ARC model is said to be a path to a future rooted type language, where all variables are objects.

Comment: @LU RD: where is that said about the ARC model and the pure object language thing?

Comment: @SideS.Fresh, see [Give in to the ARC side](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2013/06/14/38948), last section.

Comment: I also struggle to see benefits to ARC

Comment: The [documentation is still unacurate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/LLVM-based_Delphi_Compilers). ARC was removed, so perhaps pointers may be less deprecated. As you stated, they do still make sense in low-level code.